# Android image from gallery intent

Tags: android, image, image-gallery, android-gallery

Why when I load an image from the gallery with the intent, this is not rotated. As if viewed through the Android Gallery that is rotated?

===========================================

**I solved this way**:

```
int orientation=getOrientationImageFile();

    Canvas c=new Canvas(bmO);

    if(orientation!=0){
        Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(orientation);
        c.drawBitmap(bm, matrix, new Paint());

        bm=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmO, 0, 0, bmO.getWidth(), bmO.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

private int getOrientationImageFile() {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(column_index);
}
```

**selectedImageUri**-it's the DATA returned from intent Gallery

**bmO**-bitmap created by selectedImageUri

I tried and tried and it works, but is the solution, or is it a solution that can go? There are other better solutions?

Comment: Please elaborate more on your issue.

Comment: @ coder_For_Life22 For example, if I take a picture with the phone in landscape pictures in the Gallery Android is displayed good, but if I load the intent Gallery, this is not rotated and there is quite a bit of black border above and below the image. It happens regardless of whether the automatic screen rotation is set or not.

Answer (score 1):

Because Android gallery app do it for you. So, you need to implement such thing by yourself

Don't worry - it's easy: [How to crop and rotate image programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571509/how-to-crop-and-rotate-image-programmatically-in-android)